# Sonata Admin Bundle - RouteCompiler error because of placeholder longer than 32 char

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have just updated my packages using composer, and since then Symfony throws an error. Before the update, my application was running fine.

#### Error:

> Variable name "childChildChildChildChildChildChildId" cannot be longer than 32 characters in route pattern "/admin/project/rest/member/{id}/shelves_member/{childId}/contributor/{childChildId}/series/{childChildChildId}/shelves_series/{childChildChildChildId}/post/{childChildChildChildChildId}/tag/{childChildChildChildChildChildId}/event/{childChildChildChildChildChildChildId}/edit". Please use a shorter name.

### Explanation:

It appears that the admins are nested pretty deeply in the admin.yml, which makes the dynamically-generated 'childchild...' placeholder longer than 32 characters, which in turn throws an error since the RoutingCompiler.php from Symfony has a limit for placeholders defined by the constant VARIABLE_MAXIMUM_LENGTH to 32 char.

I haven't found anything in the sonata documentation regarding custom placeholders or setting a maximum length for them.

Right now, the only way I found to get the application to work after updating is to change this constant to 64 characters, but I'm pretty sure it's not a good idea as it could break things elsewhere.

(edit: added stacktrace)

#### Stacktrace

```
 in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCompiler.php at line 116  -

                }
                if (strlen($varName) > self::VARIABLE_MAXIMUM_LENGTH) {
                    throw new \DomainException(sprintf('Variable name "%s" cannot be longer than %s characters in route pattern "%s". Please use a shorter name.', $varName, self::VARIABLE_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, $pattern));
                }
                if ($isSeparator && strlen($precedingText) > 1) {

at RouteCompiler ::compilePattern (object(Route), '/admin/project/rest/member/{id}/shelves_member/{childId}/contributor/{childChildId}/series/{childChildChildId}/shelves_series/{childChildChildChildId}/post/{childChildChildChildChildId}/tag/{childChildChildChildChildChildId}/event/{childChildChildChildChildChildChildId}/edit', false)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCompiler.php at line 65  +
at RouteCompiler ::compile (object(Route))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Route.php at line 594  +
at Route ->compile ()
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/Dumper/PhpMatcherDumper.php at line 387  +
at PhpMatcherDumper ->groupRoutesByHostRegex (object(RouteCollection))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/Dumper/PhpMatcherDumper.php at line 125  +
at PhpMatcherDumper ->compileRoutes (object(RouteCollection), true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/Dumper/PhpMatcherDumper.php at line 96  +
at PhpMatcherDumper ->generateMatchMethod (true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/Dumper/PhpMatcherDumper.php at line 76  +
at PhpMatcherDumper ->dump (array('class' => 'appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher', 'base_class' => 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\RedirectableUrlMatcher'))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php at line 306  +
at Router ->Symfony\Component\Routing\{closure} (object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
at call_user_func (object(Closure), object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory.php at line 46  +
at ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory ->cache ('/var/www/serverv2/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php', object(Closure))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php at line 308  +
at Router ->getMatcher ()
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php at line 256  +
at Router ->matchRequest (object(Request))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php at line 157  +
at RouterListener ->onKernelRequest (object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func (array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php at line 61  +
at WrappedListener ->__invoke (object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func (object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php at line 184  +
at EventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php at line 46  +
at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php at line 133  +
at TraceableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 116  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php at line 57  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 67  +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php at line 183  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in web/app_dev.php at line 32  +
```

Sonata packages

`$ composer show --latest 'sonata-project/*'
sonata-project/admin-bundle                  3.34.1 3.34.1 The missing Symfony Admin Generator
sonata-project/block-bundle                  3.12.1 3.12.1 Symfony SonataBlockBundle
sonata-project/cache                         1.0.7  1.0.7  Cache library
sonata-project/core-bundle                   3.9.1  3.9.1  Symfony SonataCoreBundle
sonata-project/datagrid-bundle               2.3.1  2.3.1  Symfony SonataDatagridBundle
sonata-project/doctrine-extensions           1.0.2  1.0.2  Doctrine2 behavioral extensions
sonata-project/doctrine-mongodb-admin-bundle 3.1.1  3.1.1  Symfony Sonata / Integrate Doctrine MongoDB ODM into the SonataAdminBundle
sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle           2.5.0  2.5.0  Symfony SonataEasyExtendsBundle
sonata-project/exporter                      1.8.0  1.8.0  Lightweight Exporter library
sonata-project/formatter-bundle              3.4.1  3.4.1  Symfony SonataFormatterBundle
sonata-project/google-authenticator          1.1.0  1.1.0  Library to integrate Google Authenticator into a PHP project
sonata-project/user-bundle                   3.6.0  3.6.0  Symfony SonataUserBundle`

Symfony packages

`$ composer show --latest 'symfony*'
symfony/monolog-bundle     2.11.1  v3.2.0 Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge     v3.1.5  v4.0.8 Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-apcu      v1.7.0  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill backporting apcu_* functions to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu  v1.7.0  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related data and classes
symfony/polyfill-mbstring  v1.7.0  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php54     v1.7.0  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.4+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php55     v1.7.0  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.5+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php56     v1.7.0  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php70     v1.7.0  v1.7.0 Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util      v1.7.0  v1.7.0 Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/security-acl       v3.0.1  v3.0.1 Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access Control List)
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle v2.3.11 v3.0.3 Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony            v2.8.38 v3.4.8 The Symfony PHP framework`

PHP version

`$ php -v
PHP 5.6.33-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Jan  5 2018 15:46:26)`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably you should report this as a bug.

Comment: can you give us the stack trace, is a Symfony or Sonata issue?

Comment: the 32 char limit for placeholder is defined in Symfony. The issue is in Sonata, as it creates dynamically placeholders that are longer than the limit if your child admins are nested deeply enough. I have added the stacktrace

Comment: @OlivierMaurel the only thing we could do is make a shorter name, could you open an issue on Admin Bundle, please?

Comment: @kunicmarko20 Thanks for your help! I have submitted the issue on github.

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/5072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and after reading through the issue you added to github I resolved this as follows:

First I created my own `AbstractAdmin` that extends Sonata's.

All my Sonata admin classes then extend my abstract admin instead.

In my `AbstractAdmin` I override the `getIdParameter()` method to force Sonata to use a shorter placeholder - 'c' instead of 'child':

```
<?php
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin as SonataAbstractAdmin;

abstract class AbstractAdmin extends SonataAbstractAdmin
{
    public function getIdParameter()
    {
        $parameter = 'id';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->getChildDepth(); ++$i) {
            $parameter = sprintf('c%s', ucfirst($parameter));
        }

        return $parameter;
    }
}
```

Note that this does not allow for unlimited nesting - just for a lot more.

There's no way around the overall limit of 32 chars per placeholder that's been imposed by Symfony.

As you pointed out yourself, it's a constant that could be overwritten but that's probably not a good idea.

For reference: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/5072